# API Sentry, не работают параметры отбора получения данных

Tags: python, requests

Следующим образом пытаюсь получить данные из Sentry со статусом **resolved**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {'status': 'resolved'} 
issues = "https://sentry.ru/api/0/projects/sentry/PROJECT/issues/"
r = requests.get(issues, 
                 headers=headers,
                 data=data,
                 verify=False).json()
```

В итоге получаю все **issues** со всеми статусами и всего 100 **issues** (а их гораздо больше).

Пробовал так делать, но тоже прилетают данные со всеми статусами и тоже только 100.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
issues = "https://sentry.ru/api/0/projects/sentry/PROJECT/issues/?status=resolved"
r = requests.get(issues, 
                 headers=headers,
                 verify=False).json()
```

P.s. тега Sentry нет и задать я его не могу.

Comment: у вас вместо "Bearer TOKEN" - ваш токен? не пробовали добавлять user-agent?

Comment: Да, токен. Дело в том, что выгружать удается, дело не в user-agent. Не работают параметры при выгрузке. То есть не могу выбрать нужный статус.

Comment: Столкнулся с той же проблемой, завёл issue в setnry - https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/27147 возможно это вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

В sentry api реализованна cursor-like пагинация.
Вы можете получить query-параметр "cursor" из заголовков ответа (response.headers.get('Link')). Таким образом получить следующие 100 issues, за ними следующие и т д.
К сожалению, судя по комментариям разработчиков - на данный момент это единственный способ.

[Официальный комментарий разработчика](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/27147).

по поводу unresoved - попробуйте передать параметры таким образом:

```
/issues/?limit=25&project=6&query=is%3Aunresolved&statsPeriod=14d
```